# How to test CPU exceptions in an x86 emulator?

Tags: x86, emulation

We are writing a specialized emulator to emulate x86 programs, and we unit test the instructions by comparing its effects with the real thing. It's accomplished by setting a breakpoint in the debugger, then examining the registers, flags and various memory addresses whether they set to the same value as in the emulator at the given point.

It works very well for testing normal operation.

But how can we unittest CPU exceptions that can arise? Eg. segfaults, zero divison and such?
Is it possible to obtain the exception interrupt number or something like that with an ordinary user mode debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm assuming correctly that you're building a user-mode emulator, you will have to implement exception handling yourself. Per the manuals, when the processor responds to an interrupt or exception, it halts execution of the current task, and switches to a handler installed for that exception condition in the IDT (with some exceptions, like SMI). Application programs can access those handlers, but I'm not sure if that would be useful to you. Additionally, keep in mind that some interrupts/exceptions may save related state (consult the instruction reference manuals).

At any rate, you can install handlers (in your emulated CPU) to keep track of exceptions and state when occurred so you can unit-test them.

Comment: Implementing exception handlers in the emulator is the easier part. 
The problem is I want to verify the correctness of our emulator by comparing it to the real CPU. For example I divided by zero (integer division), can I install a handler for INT 0 in user-mode? So I can verify in the debugger whether it's really executed as I would expect, and compare it with the emulator.

Comment: No, you cannot install exception handlers in user mode. You would have to modify and recompile your kernel. You can still verify your emulator against the x86 specifications, though.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think so. Consider a page of memory sapped to disk. When you access it, a page fault is generated, the kernel intercepts it, reads the page back from disk, and restarts the execution as if nothing happened.

So, the real problem is that you can't verify **in user mode** the behavior of instructions **which exit user mode**. The same applies in fact to a `SYSCALL`.

Comment: So does this mean, the observed behavior in user-mode is heavily depends on the OS and the OS version? Does this mean one cannot simply test whether INT 0 handler is really called when divide by zero?