# Bootloader - LBA28 in Long Mode not working

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, fasm

After entering long mode from bootloader, copying the second sector in memory using LBA28 crashes the PC. The second sector was copied successfully
in memory in 32 bit mode.
The crash happens when executing the instruction

```
 rep insw
```

Is there a separate instruction for 64 bit mode?

I'm using Bochs as emualtor

Code:

```
; ---------------------------------- Load Data From Disk --------------------------------------

mov     dx,0x1F1
mov     al,0h
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f2h
mov     al,2          ; number of sectors to read
out     dx,al


mov     dx,1f3h
mov     al,1        
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f4h
mov     al,0       
out     dx,al

mov     dx,1f5h      
mov     al,0
out     dx,al

mov     dx,0x1F6
mov     al,0xE0
out     dx,al


mov     dx,1f7h
mov     al,20h   ; 20h read   30h write
out     dx,al

mov ecx, 4

loop1:
        mov dx, 1F7h
        in al, dx

        test al, 10000000b
        jnz short retry
        test al, 00001000b
        jnz short data_ready
retry:
        dec ecx
        jg short loop1
loop2:
        mov dx, 1F7h
        in al, dx

        test al, 10000000b   ; Check BSY
        jnz short loop2
        test al, 00100001b   ; Check ERR and DF
        jnz short fail
data_ready:

        mov dx, 0x1F0
        mov cx, 256*2
        mov edi, 2000000

        rep insw

        mov     rax,'L O N G '
        mov     [0B8000h],rax

      hlt

fail:
        mov     rax,'F A I L '
        mov     [0B8000h],rax
hlt
```

Comment: Try to temporarily replace `rep insw` with `rep stosw`. If this will crash, you might have some issue with accessing memory addressed by `es:rdi`.

Comment: The issue was in the addressing, changing it to 1000000 doesn't fault. But changing it to a higher memory location ( 4000000 ) faults.  The memory size in the emulator is set to 128MB, 4MB is well under that. What else do I need to check?

Comment: I would check which exception occurs when [INS](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ins:insb:insw:insd) is executed in your CPU mode, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: 0x0000000000007d34>> rep insw word ptr es:[rdi], dx : F3666D
exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting

Comment: (13) is *General Protection Fault*, check whether it occurs when you replace the faulting instruction with `rep stosw`. If yes, it might be related to incorrect setting of *Page Fault* handler or memory protection on the page addressed by RDI.  I would try to change RDI or omit the `rep` prefix. Didn't you forget to clear DF?  *IOPL* seems to be OK,, because `out dx,al` works. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761211/how-to-test-cpu-exceptions-in-an-x86-emulator

Comment: Did you reload `es` after switching to long mode?  Let's see a [mcve] including your initialization code.

Comment: `mov cx, 256*2` only writes the low 16 bits of `rcx`, so the high 48 bits could have garbage and make the count incorrect.  Does `mov ecx, 256*2` help (moves to a 32-bit register automatically zero the high 32 bits)?